# How do you bring back alternate records based on a particular criteria in SQL?

Tags: sql

I’m hoping someone can help me on this.
The code below brings back orders linked to all parts including parts with composites.
So if a set consists of a **Right** and **Left** part it will bring back SKUs ending with **R**, **L** and **A** which is a set and this is what the system calls a composite.

What I’m looking to do is write a script where if the order is marked as **TRUE** in the **bContainsComposites** field that it will bring back the SKU which is set and ignore the other parts exclude the records that are **Right** and **Left**.

However if the part / SKU in the order is not a composite marked as **FALSE** then to bring back that record.

The tables and fields concerned are as below:

```
SELECT o.[nOrderID],
oi.[ChannelSKU] AS 'OrderItemSKU',
si.[bContainsComposites]
FROM  [Order] o INNER JOIN
[OrderItem] oi
ON o.[pkOrderID] = oi.[fkOrderID]
LEFT JOIN [StockItem] si
ON  oi.[fkStockItemId] = si.[pkStockItemID]
```

The selection criteria needs to be based on the **[StockItem].bContainsComposites** which is either **TRUE** or **FALSE**

The results I'm currently getting look like the first table below.

| nOrderID | OrderItemSKU | bContainsComposites |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 285705 | EWS10323A.5 | TRUE |
| 285705 | EWS10323 | FALSE |
| 285706 | EWS10575R | FALSE |
| 285706 | EWS10575A | TRUE |
| 285706 | EWS10575L | FALSE |
| 285713 | 631113591N | FALSE |

I need the records to come back as below:

| nOrderID | OrderItemSKU | bContainsComposites |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 285705 | EWS10323A.5 | TRUE |
| 285706 | EWS10575A | TRUE |
| 285713 | 631113591N | FALSE |

EWS10323A.5 and EWS10575A are both composites so will be TRUE but 631113591N is not a composite part so is FALSE.

I need to find a way to write the script based on the second illustrated table which is to include composite parts for that order but ignore the parts that are not composite for the same order where a composite part is present. Where an order does not have a composite part I still need it to bring that record back.

In a nutshell what I need to write is something like this but in SQL:

If a COUNT of  nOrderID >1 then bring back the record which is si.[bContainsComposites] = 1, otherwise bring back the record which is si.[bContainsComposites] = 0

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh  sample data with my script above looks like this below I need it to pick up the SKU with an A on the end as it is a set (not all sets have an A on the end) and sets are identified as TRUE in the [StockItem].bContainsComposites  field.
nOrderID      OrderItemSKU
101333 10214008
101333 10214008A
101333    10214007

Comment: Hey, not as comment. Edit your question instead!

Comment: @jarlh got it will do

Comment: @jarlh just added  sample data table as requested its a complex one because what I need is to include composite parts for that order but ignore the parts that are not composite where a composite part is present. Where an Order does not have a composite part I still need it to bring that record back.

Comment: Can you add the bContainsComposites column to your sample data? This seems like a straightforward boolean logic question, but it's hard to tell

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid just added the composites field to the sample table

Comment: Your query returns 2 columns but your sample data has three columns.  I'm confused.

Comment: @GordonLinoff well spotted I've made many edits since my original post as its a difficult query to post its best explained in person. I have however amended the script. and I will try the RANK script you've suggested and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a prioritization query.  You can do this with `rank()`:

```
SELECT oc.*
FROM (SELECT o.nOrderID, oi.ChannelSKU AS OrderItemSKU, si.bContainsComposites,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY o.nOrderID ORDER BY si.bContainsComposites DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [Order] o INNER JOIN
           OrderItem oi
           ON o.pkOrderID = oi.fkOrderID LEFT JOIN
           StockItem si
           ON oi.fkStockItemId = si.pkStockItemID
     ) oc
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```